# Why I see this in my URL

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site have this weird #not-set:all suffix after update. I don't know what's that. Some plugin? Anyone have similar thing?

https://meanttomove.pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try deactivating all plugins and then put them on one by one until you find the one which does it